# Radio button not displayed after toggle list in jQuery

Tags: jquery, radio-button, html-lists

I use jQuery to hide/display a category with their children. When i hide the children and show it again, the radio button exist but it is not shown. I do not add any new elements or remove one or something.

Here is the HTML Code:

```
<ul>
<li>
    <div class="term-reference-tree-button term-reference-tree-button-processed"></div>
    <div class="parent-term">1st sample cat</div>
    <ul class="term-reference-tree-level " style="overflow: hidden; display: block;">
        <li>
            <div class="form-type-radio form-item-field-category-und form-item radio">
                <input type="radio" id="edit-field-category-und-45" name="field_category[und]" value="45" class="form-radio">  
                <label for="edit-field-category-und-45">child of 1st sample cat </label>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="form-type-radio form-item-field-category-und form-item radio">
                <input type="radio" id="edit-field-category-und-44" name="field_category[und]" value="44" class="form-radio">  
                <label for="edit-field-category-und-44">2nd child of 1st sample cat </label>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>
    <div class="term-reference-tree-button term-reference-tree-button-processed"></div>
    <div class="parent-term">2nd sample cat</div>
    <ul class="term-reference-tree-level " style="overflow: hidden; display: block;">
        <li>
            <div class="form-type-radio form-item-field-category-und form-item radio">
                <input type="radio" id="edit-field-category-und-19" name="field_category[und]" value="19" class="form-radio">  
                <label for="edit-field-category-und-19">child of 2nd sample cat </label>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="form-type-radio form-item-field-category-und form-item radio">
                <input type="radio" id="edit-field-category-und-12" name="field_category[und]" value="12" class="form-radio">  
                <label for="edit-field-category-und-12">2nd child of 2nd sample cat </label>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

When I click on 1st sample cat it collapses the children (child and 2nd child of 1st sample cat) using jQuery:

```
$('.term-reference-tree-button', context).once('term-reference-tree-button').click(function() {
  console.log("class was collapsed/expanded!");
  $(this).toggleClass('term-reference-tree-collapsed');
  $(this).siblings('ul').slideToggle('fast');
}
});
```

After clicking on the same icon, it expands the `<ul>` and only show me the names. 
The radio buttons are not shown again, but I can only select one child of the 1st cat.

As you can see in the long code above the `<input type="radio">` Button still exists after collapsing the `1st sample cat` again.

I only need to show them again.

I'm glad for any help.

Comment: last closing bracket should be }); instead of )}; (first curly brace and then round brace)

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar : this bracket "}" is extra . he just need to delete that bracket.

Comment: @AmitKumar, yes you are right.

Comment: please share jsfiddle

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar just a stupid copy and paste error because I've copied it from the whole .js file.

Comment: I think it will be difficult to share jsfiddle because the code is from a module from drupal.

Comment: I saw that the code works in Firefox 30.0 without problems. In the other browsers (Chrome, IE, Mobile Safari, Mobile Chrome) it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I did not test it, but even if it will not solve your problem you should definitely make sure that an id is really **unique**!
You used the ids for the radio-inputs two times (e.g. "edit-field-category-und-45").

And as a tip: Try to do not mix german and english :)

Comment: Oh sorry, just a stupid copy and paste error because the values of the categories are in german. Sorry for that, I've edited my code. 

I do not mix german and english by myself, dupal makes this. ;)